Best way to check completion of AsyncApexJob
I am trying to run apex test class using below code which run the test classes asynchronously
ApexTestQueueItem[] queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();
for (ApexClass cls : testClasses) {
    queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=cls.Id));
}
insert queueItems;            
ApexTestQueueItem item = 
    [SELECT ParentJobId, TestRunResultId ,ApexClassId  FROM ApexTestQueueItem 
     WHERE Id=:queueItems[0].Id LIMIT 1];


after which i scheduled an apex job every 5 minutes to check if the job with the parentjobId has completed i.e. test run has completed. So if the job has completed, i send request to tooling api to get code coverage.
The question is if there are any better way to check whether the ApexTestQueueItem asyncapex job run has completed besides scheduling class at intervals that checks the job completion? As using scheduled job increases the limit i am using out of 100 scheduled job per day limit.

No, there's not a great way to check without burning lots of other resources (e.g. a Queueable). Note that you can still use so-called "suicide scheduling", where a scheduled job aborts itself and schedules a new instance five minutes later (or some arbitrary time) to work within the limit of 100 jobs.
